# How to retrieve a price from inside an html block circumventing an <hr> tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python with BeautifulSoup.

I have a page with several of these html blocks:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <div class="thumbnail box-hover thumb-article-product"> <div class="ProductPicWrapper"> <div class="test"> <a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716"><img width="120" height="120" src="https://cdn.smartoys.be/catalog/images/thumbs/120_120/products/x5055856419716.JPG.pagespeed.ic.uX1UW7-Gxw.webp" title="The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset" alt="The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset" class="img-responsive" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3637984103" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"/></a> </div> </div> <div class="caption"> <p class="text-center nameart"><a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716">The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset</a></p> <p class="group inner list-group-item-heading nameart-ean text-center">5055856419716</br>Playstation 4</p> <hr> <p class="text-center article-price article-price-used ">Dès <span itemprop="price">10<span class="product-price-sm">.00&euro;</span></span></p> <p class="text-center"> <span class="label"></span> </p> <div class="text-center"> <div class="btn-group"> <a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Voir le produit</a> </div> </div> </div> </div></div>
```

I would like to retrieve the price. I managed to do it from a page I saved locally from Chrome, but the html code is very different when getting it directly online.

From the downloaded page I just did the following to get the price (took out the loops for simplicity):

```
productblocks = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "col-sm-6 col-md-3"})
gameprice = productblocks[i].find("p", {"class": "text-center article-price article-price-used "}).text.encode('utf-8').strip()[:-3].replace('Dès ','')
```

However, when doing this with the online page, the following code does not include the price section:

```
productblocks = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "col-sm-6 col-md-3"})
```

I manage to get the name, code, etc. However, it seems that the price section is missing.

```
print productblocks[0]
```

returns:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <div class="thumbnail box-hover thumb-article-product"> <div class="ProductPicWrapper"> <div class="test"> <a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716"><img alt="The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset" class="img-responsive" height="120" src="https://cdn.smartoys.be/catalog/images/thumbs/120_120/products/x5055856419716.JPG.pagespeed.ic.CdYmLZol8V.jpg" title="The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset" width="120"/></a> </div> </div> <div class="caption"> <p class="text-center nameart"><a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716">The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset</a></p><p class="group inner list-group-item-heading nameart-ean text-center">5055856419716</p></div></div></div>
```

which is obviously missing the price section. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If the html you saved vs the html you get online is different you need to look at the html you get online and build your query off of that. First thing you should do is look at the full page.Maybe do print(soup.prettify()) as soon as you make the soup. Also, it's possible that javascript is creating or populating the price elements so they don't actually exist in the soup you get. If that's the case, you may not be able to get them this way. I ran into complicated javascript and ended up having to look at the selenium project (controlling a real browser) as a way to webscrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Beautiful Soup` is not able to parse after the `hr` tag in your html. You can try this to get the price value.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3"> <div class="thumbnail box-hover thumb-article-product"> <div class="ProductPicWrapper"> <div class="test"> <a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716"><img width="120" height="120" src="https://cdn.smartoys.be/catalog/images/thumbs/120_120/products/x5055856419716.JPG.pagespeed.ic.uX1UW7-Gxw.webp" title="The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset" alt="The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset" class="img-responsive" data-pagespeed-url-hash="3637984103" onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);"/></a> </div> </div> <div class="caption"> <p class="text-center nameart"><a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716">The Elder Scrolls Online : Summerset</a></p> <p class="group inner list-group-item-heading nameart-ean text-center">5055856419716</br>Playstation 4</p> <hr> <p class="text-center article-price article-price-used ">Dès <span itemprop="price">10<span class="product-price-sm">.00&euro;</span></span></p> <p class="text-center"> <span class="label"></span> </p> <div class="text-center"> <div class="btn-group"> <a href="product_info.php?products_id=5055856419716" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Voir le produit</a> </div> </div> </div> </div></div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
productblocks = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "col-sm-6 col-md-3"})
print( productblocks[0].find("p", class_="group inner list-group-item-heading nameart-ean text-center").findNext("p").text.encode('utf-8').strip()[:-3].replace('Dès ','') )
```

**Output:**

```
10.00
```

- Find the `p` tag before `hr` and then use `findNext("p")` to get the price tag.

Comment: Thanks Rakesh! There had to be something like that. I was comparing the local and remote html blocks but they were so different that I didn't get the problem with the <hr> tag. Always learning!

Answer (score 0):

There are simpler ways (`a` contains your HTML):

```
import re
re.findall( r'span itemprop="price">(\d+)<span', a )
['10']
```